# Importing Images from a table on a website (Google Sheets)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a IMPORTHTML formula which imports a certain table from a website - but, of course, it doesn't import the images in that table too.

I was wondering how I might be able to do this.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Using vlookup, I have been able to find where the image is and everything, but I have tried using IMAGE() in a number of different places and it will never pull over the data. Really not sure how to do it.

Ideally, I would like to modify the IMPORTHTML formula in A1 to allow it to include images as well, but if I need to put it in D2 like I previously have been, then that's completely ok.

Formulas used in the images:

=IMPORTHTML("https://boards.habbousdf.com/showthread.php?tid=155","table",9)

=VLOOKUP(A2,IMPORTHTML("https://boards.habbousdf.com/showthread.php?tid=155","table",9),3,FALSE)

Comment: could not reproduce - https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9XyO.png

Comment: @player0 That's extremely strange, not sure why
https://i.imgur.com/fsIiYYf.png

Comment: @player0 Try turning on Iterative Calculations and setting max number of iterations to 10000.

Comment: Do NOT share [spreadsheets](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455)/[images](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) as the only source of data. Make sure to add input and expected output as **plain text table** to the question. [Click here](//webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855) to create a table easily. Adding such tables makes **it is easier to copy/paste**. Your question may be closed, if it isn't self contained. Your table should be a minimal example.[Your email address can also be accessed by the public](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304), if you share Google files.

Comment: @Xurq still no change even with that. interestingly it works for you so I can only think of the URL is somehow geo-restricted

Comment: @player0 Try this (Trophy XML Data sheet, red cell)
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yCnSAlHgMNTpr67m0X2qTjCeEzYbk0LNsM5RN4QOpFc/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this using the formula below

```
ArrayFormula(image(query(iferror(regexextract(lambda(x,filter(x,scan(,x,lambda(a,c,a+regexmatch(c,"table")))=*{table ID}*))(query(to_text(flatten(importdata("*{URL}*"))),"where Col1<>''",)),"src=.(.*\.png)")),"where Col1<>''",)))
```